# Program to find permutation of a string - Error

Tags: python, string, function, loops, permutation

Python Program

```
x=input("Enter any string:")
```

Taking input from user

```
z=len(x)*len(x)
y=len(x)-1
l,m=0,0
```

function to swap the values

```
def swap(s1,s2):
    g=s1
    s1=s2
    s2=g
    print(s1,s2)
    return s1,s2
```

after swapping values to be printed in this for loop

```
for i in range(0,z,1):
    s=x
    swap(s[l],s[m+1])
    print(s)
     m=m+1
     if m==y:
        l=l+1
        m=0
```

Code is not working properly but ending with the error IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: i used but not working

Comment: code will error if the input is less than 2 characters because s[1] means that x needs to be at least two characters long.

Comment: Your `swap` function returns the new swapped values, but you're not assigning them in the caller, you're just discarding them.  You need to do `s[l], s[m+1] = swap(s[l], s[m+1])` for it to have any effect.  But there's no need for the function at all, just do `s[l], s[m+1] = s[m+1], s[l]`

Comment: actually s[1] means second character of string s

Answer (score 0):

It might be the lack of brackets, for example, it might have to be:

```
if (m == y):
```